# consonant assimilation in linguistics

Tags: grammaticality, orthography, linguistics, language-change

In Old English, the word was "leofmann" and in ME, the word is "lemman (‘lover’)"

What is the change that took place to change the word?

> a.    simplification of word-initial consonant clusters
>
> b.    consonant insertion
>
> c.    metathesis
>
> d.    intervocalic voicing of fricatives
>
> e.    consonant assimilation

Comment: I would really appreciate any comments or advices. I think that it is consonant assimilation, but I am not sure.

Comment: 279810 would it be OK to post some research, or to work with guesses?

Many here might think me aggressive and still “… the change that took place to change the word?” has no useful meaning… unless you can explain one… please?

I suggest none of your examples has any relevance.

    a. simplification of word-initial consonant clusters

    b. consonant insertion

    c. metathesis

    d. intervocalic voicing of fricatives

    e. consonant assimilation

If in Old English, the word was "leofmann" and in ME "lemman (‘lover’)" so be it; then, what?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **e. consonant assimilation**.

Specifically, this is an instance of **regressive** assimilation (the *m* influences the preceding *f* ). 
It changes the **manner of articulation** (the [fricative](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Fricative), *f*, which, by the way, was pronounced as a voiced sound, [v], becomes a [nasal](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Nasal), *m*).

Comment: Though this is probably the right answer, couldn't one also call it elision/deletion or lenition, without bothering with assimilation (is it not necessary to assume the 'f' disappeared _because_ it shares features with the following 'm'?).

Comment: No, @Mitch, only e. is correct.

Comment: @Greg Can you say why?

Comment: @Mitch, It is simply a matter of terminology.  None of the other choices in the question fits the example.  The intent of the question is to test whether the student knows the relevant terminology.  This is the way multiple-choice questions on a test work.

Comment: @GregLee I wasn't thinking of this as a multiple choice test because this is not a multiple choice answering site. If it were then, sure, assimilation is the best of those five. Since this is not a multiple choice answering site, I was trying to tease out knowledge, the subtleties of one label in favor of another.

Comment: "Lenition" wasn't one of the options of the multiple-choice answers. However, I would accept lenition as well because the change [v] > [m] increases sonority - a nasal is weaker than a non-nasal (Trask 1996 "Historical Syntax", p. 56). Lenition is a very general umbrella term for different kinds of phonological changes. Elision/deletion is not a good description of the change because the spelling suggests that the sound was still pronounced, just as [m], not as [v]. Syllabification of the Middle English word was lem.man. Hence there is no deletion here.